# Marantz PM6005 potentiometer

Tags: control, volume

I am looking to change faulty, scratchy Alps potentiometer (RK168 series - 50k ohms) in my amplifier. This is not available easily but 100k is available. Will 100k work the same way as 50k without any loss in sound quality? Kindly let me know. Thanks [image]

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, check the [service manual](https://www.hifiengine.com/manual_library/marantz/pm6005.shtml).

Audio signal from the input RCA jacks is routed through a LC78212 analog switch IC for source selection, then directly to the volume pot, which is shown in the center of the block diagram.

Note this pot has an extra pin for loudness control. If you replace it with a pot which does not have this extra pin, the "loudness" button will no longer work. There might be a special part number for that, so make sure you get the right one.

Changing the pot's resistance from 50k to 100k will alter the loudness filter cutoff frequency. Might be a problem if you use it a lot, in this case you can adjust resistors and caps in the loudness circuit, ie multiply resistors by 2 so you they scale with the pot going from 50k to 100k, and divide caps values by 2 to keep the filter cutoff frequency where it was.

[image]

Now check "Volume PWB" page 34 of schematic PDF from link above. The pot's wiper goes to the preamp, which is a discrete current feedback design. If you use the "source direct" mode, the output of this preamp is routed directly to the power amp. Otherwise it goes through the tone control which uses 4580 opamps.

[image]

Since the pot's wiper only feeds two transistor bases (or 45980 opamps) it only sees a very light load. If you replace it with a 100k pot, there should be no ill effects besides a slight loss of gain due to the 56k resistor to ground at the input of the preamp. This should not be a problem, as in most amps, the volume control never goes to maximum level anyway.

**Note:**

You can try a fix before changing your volume pot.

If the pot is only scratchy in the "usual spot" where it spends most of its life, but the track is still new at other "way too loud" positions, you can fix the problem easily by lowering the gain of the whole amp, which means you'll have to turn the pot a little bit more to the right, thus using a portion of the track that isn't damaged. I used this trick on a TEAC amp with great success. It's dumb and low-tech but... hey, it's free and it works!

You can do this by replacing the 56k resistor at the input of the preamp with a lower value. This will form a voltage divider with the pot. It'll change the log curve a bit though. I didn't find this to be a problem.

You can also insert a resistive voltage divider after the Source Direct relay to attenuate the signal by a few dB.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably be OK using 100k pot instead of the 50k in an audio amplifier volume control application. The 50k pot will be driving a high impedance amplifier stage following, which is likely to be substantially higher than the max 25k output impedance of a 100k pot (compared to the max 12.5k of a 50k pot).

Given that the output impedance varies as the pot is turned, I would expect the following stage to have a capacitive loading sufficiently small to give a negligible change in 20kHz response as the pot is adjusted. Increasing the output impedance will result in more loss at 20kHz, at mid positions of the pot. If the loss increases from 0.5% to 1%, nobody would notice. If it increases from 10% to 20%, I wouldn't hear it, very few people would, but it would be easily measurable. What you get depends how much margin was originally designed into that stage. Whether it matters depends whether you want to measure or listen to your amplifier. Physiological response to tone varies quite strongly with listening level anyway.

While I could design a circuit that would totally fail to work with 100k, it would be a pathological design whose main purpose was to give you that problem.